# Rearranging data - row into multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

So I have csv file with over 1m records:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF7it.png)
I need data to be arranged differently that "params" who repeats become column/row themselves for example category1, category2, category3 (there is over 20 categories and no repeats) but all the data maintain their relations.

I tried using "pandas" and "csv" in python but i am completly new to it and i never had anything to do with such a data.

```
import csv

with open('./data.csv', 'r') as _filehandler:
    csv_file_reader = csv.reader(_filehandler)

    param = [];

    csv_file_reader = csv.DictReader(_filehandler)
    for row in csv_file_reader:
        if not row['Param'] in param:
            param.append(row['Param']);

    col = "";

    for p in param:
        col += str(p) + '; ';

    print(col);
    import numpy as np

    np.savetxt('./SortedWexdord.csv', (parameters), delimiter=';', fmt='%s')
```

I tried to think about it but data is nor my forte, any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, would you be able to post an example input and output?

Comment: i want to group data by categories in "param" row eg. whole category1 together - there is link with image in it

Comment: Is this how you want it to work? You end up with as many rows as you have categories, and each column is a different one of your 1m+ records? https://i.imgur.com/tZiIYcg.png

Comment: yes, that is what i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that should work. If you need more than one value per row normalized like this, you could edit line 9 (beginning `category`) to grab a list of values instead of just `row[1]`.

```
import csv

data = {}

with open('data.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader) # Skip header row
    for row in reader:
        category, value = row[0], row[1] # Assumes category is in column 0 and target value is in column 1
        if category in data:
            data[category].append(value)
        else:
            data[category] = [value] # New entry only for each unique category

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as file: # wb is write and binary, avoids double newlines on windows
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(['Category', 'Value'])
    for category in data:
        print([category] + data[category])
        writer.writerow([category] + data[category]) # Make a list starting with category and then listing each value
```